# AND operator in Linq Query with DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I wanna select some records from DataTable and got to bind in Dropdown list,Sometime i have to select where acc_id =1 in dataTable , In some cases i have to select where acc_id =1 and acc_id=5 .
how do i use && operator ,The below query is working good if only one condition .if i added  AND(&&) operator  got nothing in Resultsets.

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        var query = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 1 && a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 5
                    select a;

        dt = query.CopyToDataTable();
        ddlAccount.DataSource = dt;
        ddlAccount.DataTextField = "account_name";
        ddlAccount.DataValueField = "acc_id";
        ddlAccount.DataBind();
```

Assit me.

Comment: How come `acc_id` can be 5 & 1 at the same time?? And you expect it to satisfy.

Comment: One way to avoid that confusion is to use a collection of desired id's: `int[] ids = {1,2}; .... where ids.Contains(a.Field<Int64>("acc_id"))`.

Comment: Thanks guys, A  bit confused  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, you should use `or`, not `and` operator.

By the way, if you want the list of accepted `acc_id` to be more dynamic (coming from a parameter, for example), you may also do

```
var ids = new[]{1, 5};//this could be passed as parameter to a method
```

then

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(m => ids.Contains(m.Field<Int64>("acc_id")));
```

or of course

```
   var query = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
               where ids.Contains(a.Field<Int64>("acc_id"))
               select a
```

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam: It's not a `string` and it's not `String.Contains` but an `int[]` and `Enumerable.Contains` which checks if the collection contains at least one of the given `int`. So if it's 15 the row is not returned because 15 is neither 1 nor 5.

Answer (score 3):

For a record the `acc_id` can be *1* or *5* one at a time and your condition say `acc_id`  should be `1` and `5` at the same time (which is impossible). So you need to use or operator `||` instead of and operator `&&`. Now it will bring record(s) with `acc_id` 1 or 5

```
var query = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 1 || a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 5
                    select a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `or` since `acc_id`cant be both 1 and 5 at the same time.

```
where a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 1 || a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending my *comment*, You need an `Or` operator rather than `And` :-

```
var query = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 1 || a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 5
                    select a;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to retrieve record with **acc_id == 1** and **acc_id == 5**,  you should use OR. 

If using AND operator, 
when first condition **acc_id == 1**, then the record who match this must be **"acc_id = 1**.

Now, second condition **acc_id ==5**, how come an **acc_id = 1** can pass the filter of **acc_id == 5?**

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    var query = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                where a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 1 || a.Field<Int64>("acc_id") == 5
                select a;

    dt = query.CopyToDataTable();
    ddlAccount.DataSource = dt;
    ddlAccount.DataTextField = "account_name";
    ddlAccount.DataValueField = "acc_id";
    ddlAccount.DataBind();
```